# Fast hash function from 2^n-1 digit (means, binary 111....) into its sum of bits or other some small range

Tags: bitwise-operators, hash-function

I m looking for easy hash-function what would map the number, consist of ones

- from the right (means, 1,3,7,15 = in binary: 1,11, 111,1111)into in the best way summ of its digits (do not suggest just bit count function, i do not want to rely on that here)
- into in the best way, its summ of ones (1,2,3,4...) or other relative small nash value, not overlapping with others, simply because the amount of such digits is small - there are only 32 digits including 0 for integers, 64 for longs.)
  Thanks a lot, dear code hackers!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a multiplication with a value derived from a de Bruijn sequence, as is used to [count the number of trailing zeros](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn). For the relevant numbers, this gives a unique result between 0 and 31.

```
uint32_t hash(uint32_t x) {
    return (0x077CB531 * x) >> 27;
}
```

Comment: wow this is great suggestion, now, is it any way to substitute multiplication on something else here?
also it works not in all languages, depending on how mult is handled

Comment: actually is just found that amount of modula function, for example mod 37  works realy well and for 64 it is 67